# List-Unsubscribe Email Header unable to unsubscribe from given URL

Tags: php, email

I am using List-Unsubscribe Header, which i am able to see in email header but for some reason when i click on "Unsubscribe from this sender" button in email header i am not able to unsubscribe for that mailing list.

Even same url is used in email contents to unsubscribe which is working fine. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe: <http://ip-address/app/index.php?entryPoint=removeme&identifier=b5ddf136-a5bd-74f3-015c-53bcc5264831>, <mailto:unsubscribe@abc.my?subject=Unsubscribe>")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I follow this format for List-Unsubscribe:

```
 $mymail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@rte.com?subject=Unsubscribe>, 

 <http://www.rte.com/unsubscribe.php?unsubscribeid=$id>");
```

So, try this First parameter of MailTo and then HTTP.

Comment: I have tried that format as well i.e. MailTo and then HTTP. But no luck. Do we need a valid MailTo email address? Because i am trying to use HTTP which is a valid URL so do i need valid MailTo email address as well?

Comment: Thanks, thats what i suspect, will try that share the result.

Comment: @MuhammadKashifAbbasi how was it? Was it only the lack of the valid mail?